# Position fixed is not working CSS Fine using tailwind css without transform

Tags: css, css-position, tailwind-css

Position fixed is not working after removing transition. Please help

```html
<div class="w-full" id="addlayer">
  <button class="rounded-lg  bg-white  text-2xl px-5 py-3 fixed  bottom-20 right-[15%] " id="deletelayer">
    <i class="fad fa-trash"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

I am using Tailwind CSS Also I am using Chromebook

Answer (score 0):

It's not that `fixed` is not working from tailwind, you simply have some of your css mixed up.

When an element is `fixed` on a page, it's constrained to the browser viewport itself, rather than a parent element or div that has `position: relative`.

So, your button is showing up, it's simply at the bottom right-hand side of the screen. If you open chrome dev tools, you will see the button. Or perhaps change colors from white to red or something.

Here's where you can find more info out about css positioning!

https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Code example below!

```css
<div class="w-full bg-red-600 h-40" id="addlayer"><button class="rounded-lg  bg-red-600  text-2xl px-5 py-3 text-white fixed  bottom-20 right-[15%] " id="deletelayer">HERE IS YOUR BUTTON</button></div>
```

[Image to show where button is in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMSpj.png)